# Create pagination and order according to alphabet

Tags: query

is it possible to create an alphabet pagination? as well as alphabet order of a query post???

I can't a solution on this based on the regular queries.

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advanced.

UPDATED*****

Well since apparently this hard to understand, I will explain myself better.

I'm looking for a way to query post based on the alphabet order that allow me paginate **NOT** by page but alphabet first letter. In this order I cannot use default order_by = 'title' as some1 suggested.

PD: ifyou are going vote down, at least contribute with something, I don't think that is really hard to understand that more than the 50% of the users of the site don't use english as first language, so even if we do all our best to help the community we can make mistake sometimes. In this order if you are going to say "Explain yourself better" at least give an opinion of what you understood.

Comment: What are you trying to query? Posts? Pages? CPT? Taxonomies? This question needs WAY more detail.

Comment: Please revise your question with specific details of what you're trying to do, otherwise it's impossible to answer.

Comment: I just edited the post, as I said, I'm just looking for a way to paginate based on the alphabet, meaning (A, B, C, etc), and not an array based on order_by

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i wrote about something similar recently, maybe it could be helpful to you:

http://www.kathyisawesome.com/424/alphabetical-posts-glossary/

it was based off of my answer to this question:
[Group Posts by First Letter of Title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41660/how-to-build-a-directory-with-indexes-in-wordpress/)

the answer includes both my original posts_where solution and an alphabetical "menu" that for some reason i didn't write about in my tutorial

Comment: I would suggest you to look into

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

And you may check it working inside this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/alphabetic-pagination/

Answer (score 1):

WP_Query_Post() uses the same parameters as WP_Query(), so it would be something like `WP_Query_Post ( array ( 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '7' ) );`

Provided that's what you're asking, which isn't really clear.

Comment: I've tried with this, however as I mentioned I'm looking for a away to also paginate based on alphabet letters (meaning A, B, C and so on), I think I was clear enough with "alphabet pagination", anyway, thanks for you help

Comment: Ah, that is going to be a bit trickier.  You'll need to remove the post limit (so it doesn't only display X posts), then most likely create a custom function for that alphabetical pagination.  That's a bit beyond what I can bash out at the moment, but perhaps with your updated question someone else can build on this.  Also, check http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/web-programming/add-custom-wordpress-pagination-without-plugin/ for a custom pagination starting point.