# Group Posts by First Letter of Title categories

Tags: categories, permalinks

Questions is a duplicate of this one: [Group Posts by First Letter of Title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41660/group-posts-by-first-letter-of-title)

However, I was unsure whether I could ask on that, or I had to start a new question, so I did the latter ;)

I implemented the solution that @helgatheviking suggested in 2014 and it works/worked brilliantly, however - I have to do another list for 2015, I have tried to figure out how to separate the categories into two different lists but can't do it.... I have a category called 2014 & 2015

I tried to alter this line:

```
$posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1) );
```

by adding 'category' => x but that didn't work as I thought it might...

Any help would be fantastic and thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you need A-Z categories for 2014 and then, entirely separate from that, you need A-Z categories for 2015?

Comment: *that didn't work as I thought it might*. What did you expect the output to be and what did you actually get. This info can be handy to someone that will answer your question :-)

Comment: Sorry for my delay in replying, I was on a photo shoot...

m0r7if3r - yes, two entirely separate A-Z's...

PieterGoosen I thought somehow it would've filtered the categories into the correct taxonomies - to be honest, I still don't fully understand taxonomies, the solution that helgatheviking was the best solution I could find at the time and worked perfectly...

Comment: @Andy In that case, see my answer below, it should at least get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this, as I am more comfortable with it.

There are two solutions to this that occur to me.  If you're not heartset on the categories, then [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has good support for date parameters, to include a `year` parameter.  A query by year would look something like this:

```
$wpse176213_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'nopaging'  => true,            // return all posts
    'year'      => $your_year_var   // Must by 4 digit
) );
```

If you're heartset on using your categories, [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) also supports that.  That would look something like this:

```
$wpse166213_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'nopaging'  => true,            // return all posts
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        // Whatever the slug for the year category is
        'terms'     => $your_year_slug
    )
) );
```

Note that, if you like, you can do a simpler query without using `tax_query`, but I tend to favor `tax_query` as it allows you to extend the code with less additional effort, if you ever run into that.  Also note that these queries are not complete, I strongly recommend you read through the (long) list of available parameters and make sure you set them up correctly.  See the [codex entry for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: As above, I came in late after a photoshoot, I will definitely try this first thing in the morning as well as looking at the codex with a fresh set of eyes, I really do appreciate your time. thanks again :)

Comment: @Andy If it throws an error, LMK and I'll update the code to reflect a more accurate answer as relevant.

Comment: Hey @m0r7if3r - I've had a hectic couple of days and not free to try this till Saturday now  - I promise I will get back to you though.

Comment: Sure, just post a comment on the answer or something so that I get a notification.

Comment: apologies for how long it took to get back to you (had a massive project on the go), it worked a treat, so thank you massively.